# How to reuse multiple apps from a django project with another django project?

Tags: python, django

I have a project with multiple apps that I want to reuse in a number of other django projects, I've been looking through the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/reusable-apps/ but that example only uses a single app I'm wondering if theres anything I need to watch out for considering I want to use more than a single app across my other projects

Comment: An application in Django can contain other applications. Just wrap your apps in a single app and follow the guide.

Comment: Ah okay so I can bundle my apps into a single app? How do I go about doing that is there a process to follow or is it as simple as dragging my app directories into a single folder then following the reusable apps tutorial as if that was my only app? Thanks dude

Comment: It's basically the same routine as if they're "root" apps. You can define the `urls.py` to include the childrens `urls.py` and so on. You need to reference the apps correctly though, as in `INSTALLED_APPS` you need to refer to them as `app1.app2` etc.

Comment: Any idea where I can see a working example of this? Do you mean the urls.py inside the project I want to reuse apps from?